# Test Python Tkinter GUI application without displaying elements

Tags: python, testing, tkinter, python-unittest.mock

How to test tkinter gui without displaying elements? This should make a test quicker. Code below works, but one has to close tkinter windows after runing test to make them ends, is there a possibility to test `Next` class without running tkinter app or just do not display it? I heard about `unittest.mock`, but when i try to mock tk.Tk() it crashes.
Related: [pygtk test](http://unpythonic.blogspot.com/2007/03/unit-testing-pygtk.html), [unittest gtk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206807/whats-the-recommended-way-to-unittest-python-gui-applications), [test tkinter - old explantation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083796/how-do-i-run-unittest-on-a-tkinter-app)

```
 import tkinter as tk


class Base(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self.parent)
        self.transient(parent)
        self.overrideredirect(1)
        self.parent = parent
        self.title = title
        color = '#%02x%02x%02x' % (122, 17, 117)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bg=color, relief='raised')
        # etc.


class Next(Base, object):
    def __init(self, parent, title, color='white', **kwargs):
        Base.__init__(parent, title)
        kwargs['cancel'] = self.cancel
        kwargs['tk_entry_color'] = color
        self.pg = KeyPage(self.canvas, title, **kwargs)

    def cancel(self):
        self.pg.clean()
```

And test class:

```
class TestNext(unittest.TestCase):

@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    pass

@classmethod
def tearDownClass(cls):
    pass

def setUp(self):
    self.root = tk.Toplevel()
    self.title = 'test_next'
    self.kwargs = {'cancel': None}


def tearDown(self):
    self.next = None
    if self.root:
        self.root.destroy()

def test_init(self):
    page = Next(self.root, self.title, **self.kwargs)
```

Comment: I found that: `self.root.after(time_in_ms, lambda: self.root.destroy())` works, but is there a better solution?

Comment: btw self.root.after(time_in_ms, self.root.destroy) is shorter